# TSQL count case alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, alias

Good Morning,

I'm trying to create a simple count statement and when it returns the count it displays an alias for each column.

For example d=dog, c=cat, b=bird

```
select animal, count(animal)
from pets
group by CASE
when animal='d' then 'dog'
when animal='c' then 'cat'
when animal='b' then 'bird'
else 'others'
```

currently it throws an error about it not being grouped by the first animal but when i do put animal there it returns

```
 d  1
 c  3
 b  0
```

What I'm trying to get it too display is

```
dog 1
cat 3
bird 0
```

Comment: You need to add the `CASE` statement that changes the letters to the animal name in your `SELECT` also.

Comment: @AdamWenger thank you, first time using case!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? 2005, 2008, 2012?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(animal), 'Animals'=CASE
when animal='d' then 'dog'
when animal='c' then 'cat'
when animal='b' then 'bird'
else 'others'
from pets
group by CASE
when animal='d' then 'dog' 
when animal='c' then 'cat'
when animal='b' then 'bird'
else 'others'
```

Comment: Hey, it's great you've got an answer - but a little bit of explanation would make it even better. Don't forget that lots of total newbies come to Stack Overflow, and we like our newbies to leave, more educated than they came. Something that might be obvious to you might not be so to them - so it's always good to explain what you changed and why the change makes it better. :)